# $f$ be a non constant entire, which of the following is possible?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ be a non constant entire, which of the following is possible?

1. Re(f(z))=Im(f(z))
2. $|f|<1$
3. Im(f(z))< 0
4. $f\ne 0$

as $f$ non constant so all $1,2,3$ are false as they would imply $f$ as constant.

so true is $4$ say $f(z)=e^z\ne 0$. thank you for a confirmation.

Comment: Confirmed.${}{}$

Comment: But what is important is not the answer but the reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two words for all three: Liouville's theorem.  A few more words: Though it applies directly to #2, you have to use some simple conformal maps to make it apply to #1 and #3.

Comment: For 1 I would use directly Cauchy's equations. It is less cumbersome.

Comment: True enough!  I had a hammer, I saw three nails.

Comment: Even easier for $1$: The image lies on the line $y = x$, so the function must be constant by the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @Ayman Is the open mapping theorem easier?  Once you leave the basics I don't think you can linearly rank these things; certainly, Wikipedia's proof of it quotes several major results, namely the isolation of zeros and Rouche's theorem.

Comment: I'm not saying that the proof of the open mapping theorem is easier. *Applying* it here is easier.

Comment: Oh, yes, it does definitely apply directly.

Answer (score 0):

[Picard's Little Theorem can be directly applied to 1,2 and 3.!](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PicardsLittleTheorem.html)